# how do I add dynamic environment variable (RouteURL) to application server (deployment.yaml) using kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kustomize

I'm creating a pod for Databse server first and then an application server pod in openshift.
And I'm doing it in Jenkinsfile, with openshift deployments handled by Kustomize.

And the database routeurl varibale -DATABASE_DYNAMIC_ROUTEURL is in jenkinsfile.

Below are my manifest files for deployment.

**kustomization.yaml**

```
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- deployment.yaml
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 30
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myregistry.com/myapp:5c3dda6b
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: Always
         env:
        - name: DATABASE_DYNAMIC_ROUTEURL
          value:https://xyz-1234-databaseurl.com
        imagePullSecrets:
        - name: myregistry.com-registry-key
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 8080
```

I tried using kustomize patch to replace the value but it's not understanding the exact position to replace the value.

```
- patch: 
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/image/0/value
        value: DATABASE_DYNAMIC_ROUTEURL
```

I am new to kustomize, can someone suggest which approach is good to implement the dynamic environment variable in deployment.yaml of application server file.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try out something like

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      name: demo
      annotations: {} # initially unset. You may provide default values if you wish.
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: demo
        image: demoimage
        env:
        - name: DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.annotations['environment']
```

**kustomization.yaml** file

```
- op: replace
  path: /spec/template/metadata/annotations/environment
  value: Production
```

You can also use the **config map** to store the environment config and add or inject it further to deployment.

You can checkout this nice article : https://blog.stack-labs.com/code/kustomize-101/

Comment: harsh Manvar - Thanks for the reply.I have a doubt could you please answer, the DATABASE_DYNAMIC_ROUTEURL is a variable is defined in jenkinsfile which conatins the route url of DB server  and it change in every deployment. so if i mention the variable in config-map yaml or env file how does it understand the actual route url?
becuase after deployment it showing me DATABASE_DYNAMIC_ROUTEURL=${ROUTE_URL}      expected result:-
DATABASE_DYNAMIC_ROUTEURL=https://xyz-1234-databaseurl.com